# get_search_link() redirects to 404 template page

Tags: templates, search, 404-error

I built a custom theme, and in it, there is a 404.php page and a search.php page.

Elsewhere in the template, I wanted to link to the search page directly. So, I used the get_search_template() function to get the search page link, which results in a link like this: http://example.org/search

When I click the link, I get sent to the 404 page template.

Why is it going to the 404 page template instead of the search page template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Confusingly WordPress does not have a concept of a simply *search* page, it only has concept of *search results* page. The difference is critical because search without search query 404s as you are seeing.

If you want dedicated search page you would have to implement it as custom one, see [Codex > Creating a Search Page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Search_Page).

Comment: Those instructions are for wordpress 2.5 and don't work with 3.5.1.

Comment: Elaborate by updating your question or asking new one? It might be outdated in details, but it seems fine to me _conceptually_.

Comment: Details matter ;) Anyway, I was able to figure it out. The template page needs to be named `page-search.php`. A page named "Search" must be created in the wordpress dashboard.